# Approximate age of Geralt when he is getting Ciri

Tags: the-witcher

Is there any source to approximate or say out right the age of Geralt at the moment he gets Ciri? (by "gets" I mean inherits from the Law of Surprise)

Books and/or games accepted, no fan-fiction(except from the games) please!

Comment: Sure, ask Witcher questions when I'm asleep, why not.

Comment: @gallifreyan - I am giving people chances, who knows what might happen! Don't be greedy!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the time of *Baptism of Fire*, Geralt is "past fifty", according to an interview with Andrzej Sapkowski I found on a [Russian fan-site](http://www.sapkowski.su/modules.php?name=Articles&pa=showarticle&artid=1195). The nature of Sapkowski's answer makes it impossible to determine his age at the moment of *Something More*, but we know that about 3 years have passed between their reunion in *Something More* and *Baptism of Fire*.

Here's the text in Russian:

> **Вопрос**: Сколько (хотя бы приблизительно) лет Геральту? По нашим подсчетам, около 45...
>
> **АС**: Ему (в период “Крещения огнем”) за пятьдесят. Но я не признаюсь и никому не скажу, насколько за. Ведьмаки стареют дольше, чем обычные люди и менее заметно, чем обычные люди. Ведьмаку которому лет шестьдесят, тоже никто не даст больше, чем сорок пять. Правда, в Мире ведьмака средний возраст людей больше, чем в “нашем” средневековье, но однако и тут вряд ли бы поручили мокрое дело борьбы с чудовищами “дедку за пятьдесят”. Поэтому Геральт скрывает возраст.

My translation (with input from @scrwtp, emphasis mine):

> **Q**: How old (at least approximately) is Geralt? According to our calculations, he must be around 45...
>
> **AS**: (At the time of *Baptism of Fire*) he's **past fifty**.  (At the time of *Baptism of Fire*) he's **past fifty**. But he never tells anyone exactly how old he is. Witchers age slower than ordinary people, and they don't age as visibly as ordinary people. A witcher who is 60 years old will appear to be 45. Although in the world of the Witcher average [life expectancy] is slightly higher than in "our" medieval ages, still, no one will hire a "50 year old gramps" to do such demanding task as hunting monsters. So Geralt has to hide his age.

Original Polish text, as [archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20071215043502/http://www.sapkowski.pl/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=453) from Sapkowski's own website:

> **Piotr Szczygielski**: Ile (choćby w przybliżeniu) lat ma Geralt? Z naszego szacowania wynika, że około 45 lat...
>
> **AS**: Ma (w chwili "Chrztu ognia") ponad pięćdziesiąt. Ale nie przyznaje się i nikomu nie powiedział, ile ponad. Wiedźmini starzeją się wolniej od zwykłych ludzi i mniej widocznie, niż zwykli ludzie. Wiedźminowi, który ma lat sześćdziesiąt, też nikt nie da więcej niż czterdzieści pięć. W świecie wiedźmina ludzie osiągają co prawda wyższą średnią wieku, niż w "naszym" średniowieczu, ale jednak i tu wahano by się zlecać mokrą robotę, walkę z potworami "dziadowi po pięćdziesiątce". Dlatego Geralt ukrywa wiek.

Comment: Actually, while recent interviews portray him as a grumpy old bastard, he's actually very cool according to earlier interviews. At least his views on politics, globalisation, religion, and technology are progressive.

Comment: @scrwtp thanks for improving the translation!